# In which directory should I install programs on Linux?

Tags: linux

I use Linux for 2 years at my work and I still confused where should my installed programs remain. Now I use `/opt/<program>` e.g. I've installed vim73 from sources there (reason not to use package manager is there is no 7.3 version of `VIM` in my sources e.g. `/etc/apt/sources.list` on my `Ubuntu`).

But all my programs I installed from sources previously are scattered among FS everywhere like PHP 5.3.6 remains in `/opt/local/php53`, apache in `/etc/`, vlc in `/etc/mutimedia` etc.

Is there some convention I can follow?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Absolutely. It's called the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html).

Comment: So to answer the question, according to the FHS linked above you should install programs in `/opt`.